# Getting information from database and giving it to javascript

Tags: database

The main thing I want to achieve is that my module makes a google map with markers.

For now im doing this:

```
drupal_add_js('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDcl28Qcn9GTi02rRtQaLgVS4GWZbGcQ8E', 'external');

$locations = db_query('SELECT * FROM {locations}')->execute();

$script = '<script>
     function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
      center: { lat: 56.9714744, lng: 24.1291624},
      zoom: 9
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(\'map-canvas\'),
        mapOptions);

    var locations = [';

    for($i = 0; $i < $locations->length;$i++){
        $string = '['.$locations[$i]['locationsTitle'].','.$locations[$i]['locationsLat'].','.$locations[$i]['locationLng'].'],';
        $script = $script.$string;
    }

    $script = $script.'];
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

      var loc = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: loc,
        map: map,
        title: locations[i][0]
      });
    };

  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, \'load\', initialize);

</script>
';

$html = '
<div id="map-wrapper" style="width:100%;height:500px;margin:auto">
    <ul id="map-list"></ul>
    <div id="map-canvas" style="width:100%;height:100%;margin:auto></div>
</div>
';

return array('#markup' => $script.$html);
```

As you can see in the third line of code im trying to get information from the database that I have saved. The problem is I dont know how would i get it properly. And then I want to pass it down in the var locations part in the script..

I have tried finding some tutorials where they explain how would this work but most of them is just how to show some posts or somthing like that and that doesnt help me.

Thanks for help already! :)

// EDIT

This is the script that i have now in js file

```
(function($) {
     Drupal.behaviors.myModule = {
       attach: function(context, settings) {

          function initialize() {

          var mapOptions = {
             center: { lat: 56.9714744, lng: 24.1291624},
             zoom: 9
          };
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);

    var locations = [
                    ['Mājas',56.956344, 24.197409],
                    ['Domina',56.966058, 24.162004]
                    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

      var loc = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: loc,
        map: map,
        title: locations[i][0]
      });
    };

  }

  //google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

}
```

}
 )(jQuery);

I have the "google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);" commented becouse I think i dont need it..? And becouse there is no function initialize anymore? Or should i add that back?

The problem now is that my script seems to be added.. But it doesnt seem to be run becouse the google map dosnt show up..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never need to build javascript with PHP, there's just no need (especially in Drupal, which already has a mechanism).

What you should do instead is put your JS in an external file, then use Drupal's JS settings to pass the data. So the JS file might look like:

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myModule = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      var locations = Drupal.settings.myModule.locations;
      // Do something with the locations var.
    }
  }
)(jQuery);
```

And in your page callback or whatever:

```
$settings['myModule']['location'] = db_query('SELECT * FROM {locations}')->fetchAll();
drupal_add_js($settings, 'setting');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :) Im new to js and drupal so I`ll look in to your answer and try it out :) A question about " Drupal.behaviors.myModule". Do i have to have my module name in the "myModule" part? // Edit.. I think I understood why it is myModule. Its becouse you name it here like that? $settings['myModule'] Right?

Comment: Its showing me this error:Warning: Illegal offset type in drupal_add_js() (line 4230 of /drupal/includes/common.inc)

Comment: And it dosnt seem that the javascript file is added.. This is what I placed in the info file "scripts[] = DGMap" and DGMap is the name of js.

Comment: Here is an example of use of $settings if it can help you: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/136613/use-drupal-settings-variables-on-javascript/136616#136616

Comment: I guess i need to add the js file with drupal_add_js('DGMap.js','external'); But how should i do the path to the module? I have the js in sites/all/modules/GoogleMapByDave

Comment: My script doesnt seem to run.. What could be the problem?