# Drupal Behaviours - Call specific JS function from PHP

Tags: javascript

I have a google map module – it calls google_map.js to do the JSON parsing and create icons on a map

The module calls the JS and passes the PHP variables across on this line – storing the array in the Drupal settings

```
  // call the JS map bulletin function - pass variables from your PHP to your Javascript 

drupal_add_js(array('google_map_bulletin' => $options), 'setting');
```

The JS creates the drupal behaviour and has the function which creates the projects map OK

```
// attach a function
    attach: function (context, settings) {

        // Helper function to build project map object, render map, fetch coordinates, place markers.
        function google_map_render_projects(center_coords, map_type, zoom_level, data_url, map_element_id)
```

but I need to access a 2nd function for the 2nd map to show bulletins from a different JSON call

```
google_map_render_bulletin
```

**Is there a way to call the **google_map_render_bulletin** function direct from the modules PHP code** otherwise it always calls the first one inside attach function?

FULL JS CODE

```
(function ($) {

// unique namespace (module_name) for the behaviour
Drupal.behaviors.google_map = {

    // attach a function
    attach: function (context, settings) {

        // Helper function to build project map object, render map, fetch coordinates, place markers.
        function google_map_render_projects(center_coords, map_type, zoom_level, data_url, map_element_id) {

            //console.log(center_coords, map_type, zoom_level, data_url, map_element_id);

            var canvas = document.getElementById(map_element_id);

            // Set the basic map options.
            var mapOptions = {

                center: new google.maps.LatLng(center_coords['lat'], center_coords['lng']),
                zoom: zoom_level,
                // MapTypeID options: ROADMAP, SATELLITE, HYBRID, or TERRAIN.
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId[map_type],
                streetViewControl: false,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                zoomControl: true,
                zoomControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
                }
            };

            // Instantiate the basic map object.
            var map = new google.maps.Map(canvas, mapOptions);

            // Make an ajax request to retrieve the coordinates as JSON.
            var jsonCoordinates =
              $.ajax({
                  url: data_url,
                  datatype: 'json',
                  async: false
              }).responseText;

            // parse the JSON into usable format
            var json = $.parseJSON(jsonCoordinates);

            // get the ConstructionProjects coordinates out of the JSON - $values['ConstructionProjects']['ConstructionProject'][]
            var ConstructionProjects = json.ConstructionProjects.ConstructionProject;

            // Loop through the fetched coordinates and build the markers.
            $.each(ConstructionProjects, function (index, item) {

                // Build the marker popup and HTML link
                var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: "<span>" + item.name + "<br>" + item.description + "</span>"
                });

                // Build the marker.
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.lat, item.lng),
                    map: map,
                    icon: item.icon,
                    //title: item.title
                    title: item.name
                });

                // Make the popup show when the marker is clicked.
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    info.open(map, marker);
                });

            });
        }

        // Call our map rendering function above using $options parameters passed along through Drupal.settings.
        // eg drupal_add_js(array('google_map_projects' => $options), 'setting')
        // all the options array variables are pass to the function here
        google_map_render_projects(
        Drupal.settings.google_map_projects.center_coords,
        Drupal.settings.google_map_projects.map_type,
        Drupal.settings.google_map_projects.zoom_level,
        Drupal.settings.google_map_projects.data_url,
        Drupal.settings.google_map_projects.map_element_id
      );
    // end attach function
    }

    // end namespace
};


// Function to build bulletin map
function google_map_render_bulletin(center_coords, map_type, zoom_level, data_url, map_element_id) {

    //console.log(center_coords, map_type, zoom_level, data_url, map_element_id);

    var canvas = document.getElementById(map_element_id);

    // Set the basic map options.
    var mapOptions = {

        center: new google.maps.LatLng(center_coords['lat'], center_coords['lng']),
        zoom: zoom_level,
        // MapTypeID options: ROADMAP, SATELLITE, HYBRID, or TERRAIN.
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId[map_type],
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
        }
    };

    // Instantiate the basic map object.
    var map = new google.maps.Map(canvas, mapOptions);

    // Make an ajax request to retrieve the coordinates as JSON.
    var jsonCoordinates =
      $.ajax({
          url: data_url,
          datatype: 'json',
          async: false
      }).responseText;

    //console.log("data_url=" + data_url);


    // parse the JSON into usable format
    var json = $.parseJSON(jsonCoordinates);



    // get the ConstructionSite coordinates out of the JSON - $values['ConstructionSite']['ConstructionSiteMonitor'][]
    var ConstructionSite = json.ConstructionSite.ConstructionSiteMonitor;



    // Loop through the fetched coordinates and build the markers.
    $.each(ConstructionSite, function (index, item) {

        // Build the marker popup and HTML link
        var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "<span>" + item.name + "<br>Air Quality Index: " + item.AQIndex + "<br>" + item.description + "</span>"
        });

        // Build the marker.
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.lat, item.lng),
            map: map,
            icon: item.icon,
            //title: item.title
            title: item.name
        });

        // Make the popup show when the marker is clicked.
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            info.open(map, marker);
        });

    });
}

// Call our map rendering function above using parameters passed along through Drupal.settings.
google_map_render_bulletin(
    Drupal.settings.google_map_bulletin.center_coords,
    Drupal.settings.google_map_bulletin.map_type,
    Drupal.settings.google_map_bulletin.zoom_level,
    Drupal.settings.google_map_bulletin.data_url,
    Drupal.settings.google_map_bulletin.map_element_id
  );
// END Function to build bulletin map
```

})(jQuery);

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you could be asking, especially this bit: _call the **google_map_render_bulletin function direct from the modules PHP code_ when the rest of the question's context surrounds JavaScript and not PHP. If you're asking can you invoke `google_map_render_projects` from anywhere other than the current scope, then no, because it's a private method. It will need to be somewhere more global, which is just a plain old javascript issue (Drupal doesn't have anything special to help). It would help if you could clear up what you need to know, though

Comment: Thanks

The module has this function to create a google map

    function google_map_bulletin($zoom_level=10)

Within it this line calls the JS in the Behaviour

`code`drupal_add_js(array('google_map_bulletin' => $options), 'setting'); `code`

I need it to call google_map_render_bulletin which is the 2nd function declared in the JS file

How do I call a specific function?

Comment: You can't "call" a JavaScript function from PHP, no. PHP is on the server side, JavaScript is on the client side. To make them talk you either need to use AJAX or sockets

Comment: OK so do I need a new behaviour namespace for each JS function that I pass variables to?

 Drupal.behaviors.google_map = {}


 Drupal.behaviors.google_map_2 = {}

Comment: This guy uses settings to interact with Google Map JS. I remember answer his question about that. So maybe this could help you: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/136613/use-drupal-settings-variables-on-javascript/136616#136616

Comment: So...you need to know whether there's a way to call `drupal_add_js('foo')` twice in the same page load, and _append_ settings the 2nd time round rather than overwriting the first lot? If so that's a great question, and the answer is no :) A common pattern is to have a function which accepts multiple settings, stores them in static cache, and then the same function is used nearer the actual page render to combine them all into a single settings array. Make sense?

Comment: thanks

I have a custom drupal module that creates the google map. The first map is generated using the hook_menu()

'code'
$items['projects/projects-map'] = array(
    'title' => 'Projects Map',
 // callback function to render page
    'page callback' => 'google_map_projects',
 // check user access
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
'code'

the callback function has

`code`
drupal_add_js(array('google_map_projects' => $options), 'setting');
`code`

The 2nd map is created by 


    // hard code the URL here where the bulletin page will be
 $items['projects/projects-bulletin'] = array()

Comment: `code drupal_add_js(array('google_map_bulletin' => $options), 'setting');

Comment: so for the 2nd map call back function we need to access a different function in the JS as it creates different map icons

Its not on the same page load as the map urls are different. There doesnt seem to be a way in Drupal to pass PHP vars to a specific function in a JS file using behaviours